# Unit Test Directive with Isolated Scope

Tags: angularjs

I want to unit test a directive which looks like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .directive('phone', function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        user:'=',
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
          scope.user.division = null;
          return viewValue;
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Here is my failing test

```
'use strict';

describe('Directive: phone', function () {

  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('app'));          
  var element,
    scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element('<form name="form"><input name="phone" ng-model="user.phone" phone></form>');
    scope.user = {};
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    element.scope().$digest();
  }));

  it('should work', function() {
    scope.form.phone.$setViewValue('1');
  });
});
```

But when I try to run it I get:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'scope.user.division=null')`

Comment: Yes sorry. Dumb mistake on my part.

Comment: Thanks @jpiasetz for your question. It actually helped me to fix my issue with testing isolated scope :) cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your isolate scope implies that there should be a `user` attribute on the element that references a `user` entity on the parent $scope.

In you compiled HTML, though, there is no `user` attribute, therefore your isolate $scope's `user` property is undefined.

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<input ... user="user" />
```